# Xcode iOS - multiple tests using same resource fail - how to use 1 resource for many tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have a suite of tests that I'm gradually writing that test different functions on a video file. (I include a test video in my resource bundle.) When running these tests one by one, they succeed. But when running them all together from the Xcode Test Navigator, they start producing load errors such as `"The requested URL was not found on this server."` (using AVAssetImageGenerator - similar messages of "can't find this URL" are produced for other file loading operations.)

I can get rid of these errors and have all my tests run perfectly by simply duplicating my test video and using a different file for each test case. I'm currently using `NSFileManager` and `AVAsset` classes to load videos from file URL, and my best guess at the moment is that tests are being run in parallel and my test resource video file is being locked by the system when it's in use by one thread.

This one-file-per-test scenario isn't ideal for video though as my test resource folder is quickly growing in size!

Any good ways to use one test resource across multiple tests?

**edit**: My tests span different test files, and I'm getting the file URL (which is always valid) in all cases like

```
testVideoURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"TestVideo3" withExtension:@"MOV"];
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal code example - at least two test cases that when run together would fail, along with all setup/teardown methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a helper method to load the file, and to then treat it as a pseudo-singleton?

Some very simple nil-checking would suffice, for example:

```
-(VideoClass *)loadMyVideo {
    if (_myVideo == nil) {
        VideoClass *loadedVideo;
        //  load video logic here
        _myVideo = loadedVideo;
    }
    return _myVideo;
}
```

I've had similar issues with my own testing recently, which this navigated nicely, remembering to nil-assign properties in my `tearDown` and assign them in `setUp`.

I doubt very much that the tests are being run in parallel unless you've explicitly set them to do so, as by default they run synchronously on the main thread.
If you are, however, concerned about that, then you could also try using a `dispatch_once` initialisation inside the if statement.

Comment: Hmm don't think this'll help my case - as I mention some of the code I'm testing uses NSFileManager, some uses AVAsset, these just take the file URL and do their own private thing..

Comment: Also, if the tests aren't running in parallel, then I don't understand why there would be an issue for the code "finding" the file URL a second/third time from other test units..

Comment: Could be related to how NSFileManager and AVAsset load the file, as opposed to how the tests run.
If they do so, and I suspect they likely do, with background requests, then you're out of luck unless you want to write categories for them that do the same thing in the main thread, which is likely not a great idea.
You could put in some kind of semaphore flagging to wait for these tasks to finish, I guess. But I've almost zero experience with these two classes, so I'm not sure how best to continue from here.